# node.js & mongodb, when the data is rapidly increasing, how to design data archive?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

At present, I design the platform, there will be a large number of data stored in the database every day, but these information will only be used within three days to a week, then the information is only used for future inquiries.

This large amount of information will lead to a reduction in the effectiveness of the database. My current thinking is to periodically submit the data to another DB.This DB will be used exclusively as a query.

How do I design it? Suppose I extracted once a month, how do I get this month's data from mongodb and dump it to another repository.